# Mac OSX Development - Show/Hide Buttons

Tags: macos, button, show-hide, ibaction

I have been struggling with this for a while now. I want to make it so for Mac development, when I click a button, that button hides and another one shows. I know for iOS it is

```
    -(IBAction)hide:(id)sender  { 
        button1.hidden = TRUE;
        button2.hidden = FALSE;
 }
```

And then I would initially set button 2 to hidden. How could I achieve the same affect in Mac development. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Same thing. [`setHidden:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setHidden%3a) is a method on `NSView`. You can setup the buttons initially in [`awakeFromNib`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib).